# GeoJSON for floor plan

Tags: mongodb, svg, openlayers, d3.js, geojson

While evaluating different technology to represent an office floor plan (so, basically 3d geometry data and 2d representation), I came across many new javascript package for client side representation.

I see suggestion to use openlayers.org, but afraid may be most of the features are not useful to me. I currently thinking about rendering svg model using d3js.org.

1. Is it worth the effort to learn openlayers? Would it make easier to render the floor plan from GeoJson?
2. Is there any benefit in storing the floor plan (coordinates + Height, Width, Depth data ) in GeoJson. I plan to use MongoDB and heard it natively support [geoJson](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) .Or is it enough to store the data with custom structure (class). I don't know much about GeoJson, and not sure whether the data needs to be geospatial. All the examples I saw so far is related to maps and not for geometrical shapes.

Comment: I wish the person down voted care to reason it. For me it is a genuine qn to get a direction before invest time on huge libraries.

Comment: +1 seems like a proper SO question to me

Comment: "I don't know anything about GeoJson, and not sure whether the data needs to be geospatial." is likely the reason why it got downvoted. If you don't know anything about something, go read up on it!

Comment: @Derick. I worded wrongly, and edited the post. I indeed read part of the spec and tried to find some example. But all of them were about map data. Though it can represent shapes, it in a different context with lot of other information (longitude, ..) which I may not need.

Comment: @bsr Well it's been almost 6 years. I'm in your shoes right now. Did you use GeoJSON for a floorplan? Did you use d3js? What was the result?